# How to write output of clang program to a file from shell

Tags: bash, io, clang

Hello i have the following problem:
I want to write the output of a program (in our case a `c` program) to a file.So far i have tried using `|` , `>` but to no avail:

**main.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
 printf("Echo World");
 return 3;
}
```

**Bash Command**
`gcc main.c` => i get an `exe` named `a.exe`
`./a | test.txt` or `./a > test.txt`
`cat test.txt` => `Echo World`
Whichever the method i get the `Echo World` which is normal since i am directing the `stdout` of the program to the file.
But doesn't the `return` value of a `clang` program  (in our case `3`) belong to `stdout` too? How can i get my hands on it?

Answer (score 0):

Your `return 3` is the return value of your application hence that will be considered as `exit status` of your application which will not be printed in consul or standard output. Redirection can be done on stderr (standard error) and stdout (standard output) but not the exit status. To redirect the exit status you have to do the following

```
./a > test.txt
echo $? >> test.txt
```